# Submit function not getting called when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The onSubmit tag does not seem to be working. I am trying to call the submit() javascript function when the submit button is clicked on the webpage. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.serializeJSON.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function submit() {
     .......
   }
</script>
  <div class="login-container">
    <div class="title">Login Form</div>
    <div class="form-fields">
      <form name="login-form" id="login-form" onSubmit="return submit()">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required></input>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="submit-button"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: not sure why you have closing `</input>`tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a naming conflict.

The form has a native built in function which can be seen with

```
<form id="x" onsubmit="console.log(submit);"><input type="submit"/></form>
```

When you look at the console you will see

```
function submit() { [native code] }
```

So when you call submit() you are calling that native submit function aka `document.getElementById("login-form").submit();` and not yours. To get around it, change the name.

Change the function name to something other than submit.

```
function xSubmit(){

}
```

and

```
<form name="login-form" id="login-form" onSubmit="return xSubmit()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** use "submit" as the function name. Submit is a JavaScript keyword. Simply rename your function to something else.

```
function submitForm() {
    console.log('I work now');
}

<form name="login-form" id="login-form" onSubmit="return submitForm()">
```

Comment: Where is it reserved? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar

Answer (score -2):

It should be a lowercase s.

`<form name="login-form" id="login-form" onsubmit="return submit()">`

check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp for more info.

EDIT:
Sorry, I did some testing and found out that it was the name submit.
Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9z95chze/.

You also shouldn't need to say return

Comment: not going to make a difference. It can be OnSuBmIt and it would still work.

Comment: And with your edit: You do need return if you want to cancel the form submission.

Comment: Oh, that is true. My mistake. I usually try to avoid inline JS and just do a return false. Thanks for the insight.